# Why 'Package' type does not inherit 'AccessibleObject' type?

Tags: java, inheritance, type-systems, reflection, annotations

Below are the relevant types(in java) for annotation processing,

### [image]

In addition to `Field` & `Method` types, `Package` type is also used in context of annotations with reflection, because these types implement `AnnotatedElement` interface.

This contract allows to access(in runtime) the instances of those types to get their meta data.

Why `Package` does not inherit `AccessibleObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because packages aren't accessible.  What the word "Accessible" in the name `AccessibleObject` means is effectively *has an access specification and associated scope*.  For example, an object might have `public` access (at which point its scope is irrelevant), or `private` access from within `class Foobar`, or package-local (default) access in package `com.example.foo`.  `AccessibleObject` also provides access to annotations that are declared on a Java source element, but this isn't its primary purpose.

Packages don't have this.  All packages in Java are public, and are globally accessible.  (I believe Java 9 introduces a system that is going to change this in some ways, but I believe it just introduces a new orthogonal system of classification that isn't going to affect AccessibleObject and packages).

Packages can have annotations, but access to these is provide through alternative means, so have no need to extend `AccessibleObject` to provide the relevant API for this.

This means that the methods in `AccessibleObject` (mostly `isAccessible()` and `setAccessible(boolean)`) are irrelevant for packages, because packages are always accessible and this is not something that can be set.  Therefore, extending this type would not be appropriate for them.

Comment: access thru alternative means? These types implement `AnnotatedElement`, which allows access to annotations assigned to these types.

Comment: @user1787812 You are confounding the meaning of the word "access". The term "Accessible" has a very specific meaning, and you are trying to use it in its more general, natural language way. The given answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could just as well ask "why don't `List` collections inherit from `AccessibleObject`," or any other class in Java, for that matter?  The short answer is "because they don't have to."

The `java.lang.reflect` namespace is meant to provide Reflection capabilities over any object in the Java ecosystem, *without requiring that said object inherits from a Reflection base class,* or any other class. That's kind of the whole point of reflection: to do things in Java that would normally require inheritance or composition to achieve.

You said it yourself: "Package type is used in context of annotations with reflection."  It is those annotations that Reflection is interested in, not your class inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: When you say: *that would normally require inheritance or composition to achieve*, you mean, for every class loaded by class loader, there will be a separate copy of `Class` object?

Comment: No,  I mean things that you would normally use inheritance or composition to accomplish.  Reflection doesn't require inheritance or composition (of your own classes) to function properly.